# Is it correct place to set DefaultConnectionLimit for .NET Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it a correct place to set 'DefaultConnectionLimit' for .NET Core app?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
```

Comment: you should add more information to specify what `ServicePointManager` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it in `Program.cs` , But usually we will configure some files in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`.